# CardView: How do I add a gradient background while maintaining the radius

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

I want to re-create the image below with a CardView. To achieve this, I created a gradient file (btn_gradient.xml) and then proceeded to create the CardView.

[image]

CardView implementation:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
            android:text="Create Account"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Everything works fine this way except that **the radius disappears** and this is not what I want. Is there a way I can set the gradient directly on the CardView? The `cardBackgroundColor` attribute accepts only colors, not drawables.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Addendum:** 
As requested, this is my btn_gradient.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="0"
    android:startColor="#ffc200"
    android:endColor="#fca10b" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Can you post the btn_gradient and as well an image of your result?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I felt it was unnecessary because everything actually works fine except that the CardView radius disappears and I suspect this is because of the imposing TextView. Nevertheless, I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @TaslimOseni did u got solution ?

Comment: Yes, Micho's answer worked for me. If this does not work for you, let me know. I have an idea of a better approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I may ask, are you per-chance testing/running on a **pre-lollipop** Android device? Your code seems to work as you desire (curved corners showing with the gradient) **except** on Android 4.

To achieve the desired result on pre-lollipop devices, you can add `<corners android:radius="4dp" />` to your `@drawable/btn_gradient` file, (you would have to set the corner radius to match the `CardView`'s `cardCornerRadius`.

Answer (score 21):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/_1sdp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_16"
        android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp">

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and gradient be like

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#5B86E5"
        android:endColor="#36D1DC"
        android:angle="180" />

    <corners
        android:radius="10dp">
    </corners>
</shape>
```

CardView card_radius and gradient radius should be same dimentions

Comment: Although this code snippet may answer the question, including an explanation of why and how it helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 3):

I've tried integrating the gradient on card view dynamically & faced the issue that the corner radius got impacted that was set on the view property in xml file like `app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_20"`.

**Solution :**

- Implementing the gradient on card view. I'm getting 2 gradients from api that will be incorporated from left to right.

  ```
   `    try {
               val startColor = sample?.gradient1
               val endColor = sample?.gradient2
               val colors =
                   intArrayOf(Color.parseColor(startColor), 
                   Color.parseColor(endColor))
               val gradientDrawable = GradientDrawable(
                   GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, colors
               )

               myCardView.background = gradientDrawable
           } catch (e: Exception) {
               // default color to white
               myCardView.setBackgroundColor(
                   ContextCompat.getColor(
                       mContext,
                       R.color.white
                   )
               )
           }`
  ```
- Now on running the code, the card view renders with the gradient value but the issue occurs with the corner radius of card view that was set statically at xml. The corner radius got removed. To solve the issue, we simply use to set the radius of the gradient drawable that holds the drawable color in gradient form. Just add below 3 lines before setting the background.

  ```
    gradientDrawable.colors = colors
    // setting the corner radius on gradient drawable
    gradientDrawable.cornerRadius = 40f
    myCardView.background = gradientDrawable
  ```

The final code with gradient configuration & setting the corner radius is :

```
         try {
                val startColor = sample?.gradient1
                val endColor = sample?.gradient2
                val colors =
                    intArrayOf(Color.parseColor(startColor), 
                    Color.parseColor(endColor))
                val gradientDrawable = GradientDrawable(
                    GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, colors
                )
                gradientDrawable.colors = colors
                // setting the corner radius on gradient drawable
                gradientDrawable.cornerRadius = 40f
                myCardView.background = gradientDrawable
                
                myCardView.background = gradientDrawable
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // default color to white
                myCardView.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        mContext,
                        R.color.white
                    )
                )
            }`
```

Screenshot for better view of code :
[image]

Hope this will help. Happy Coding :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Move this line

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
```

To the `CardView` object

**UPDATE**

My bad:

Inside the  place a layout to wrap the content of the .

In this case, I'd go with a `<FrameLayout>` like this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLyout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient">
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#004e92"
    android:endColor="#614385"
    android:angle="90" />
    <corners
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp">
    </corners>
</shape>
```

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/color"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/cardcolor"                    
                    android:layout_height="100dp">
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]