# How to draw this shape in XML for Android?

Tags: android, android-drawable, layer-list

[image]

I do not need you to worry about the text or gradient or shadow, I will work that out. I just don't know how to draw the outline in XML using layer-lists.

Comment: The edge of this view is not actually round for a paint Object.. So its better you should use a Image  as Background.. Probably a 9-patch image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CardView: How do I add a gradient background while maintaining the radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714392/cardview-how-do-i-add-a-gradient-background-while-maintaining-the-radius)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw a shape with rounded corners (and dont want to have this "cut shapy" shape) you just need to create drawable file using this code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <corners android:radius="25dp"/>

</shape>
```

but, if you want to make exact shape like this image, i think that you should use image on the background of button.